# append object internal state to another object

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have an **API** which return a single **record** of **language** from database. Here is my controller code I have done so far.

```
    $languages = BaseLanguage::first();
    $responseData = [
        'code' => '200',
        'languages' => $languages,
    ];
    return $this->apiResponse('status', '200', $responseData);
```

And response i get-

```
{
"code": "200",
"languages": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "English",
 }
}
```

This works fine. I was just wondering is there any way that I can get my response as follows-

```
{
    "code": "200",
    "id": 1,
    "title": "English",
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: return $this->apiResponse('status', '200', $languages);

Comment: it removes "code": "200",

Comment: $languages->code=200; after $languages = BaseLanguage::first();

Comment: wow, great, thanks :),

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
$languages = BaseLanguage::first();
$languages->code = "200";

return $this->apiResponse('status', '200', $languages);
```